# Is there a stable repo for Tuleap

Tags: tuleap

I installed tuleap using the [official installation](http://doc-en.tuleap.net/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html) instructions.  The repo referenced in the instructions is for development channel packages (baseurl=http://ci.tuleap.net/yum/tuleap/rhel/6/dev/$basearch).  My installation, version 8.11.99.38,  has issues (I can't write follow-ups to trackers, and tracker report changes don't save), and I want to install a stable version.  Is there a stable repo, or do I have to install from source? Is there a guide for installing from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you report typical happens when selinux was not disabled, I would recommend that you check the status with `getenforce`  and, if necessary, switch the configuration to `permissive`.

Otherwise, the stable repo is https://tuleap.net/pub/tuleap/yum/rhel/6/stable/x86_64/